# A specific usage of "Solve" function

Tags: equation-solving, variable

It is something from [Simplifying polynomials with conditions on variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114634/simplifying-polynomials-with-conditions-on-variables), that intend to minimize the number of variables.
The problem is the usage of ``Solve". I know how to solve equations, like

```
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]
```

However, for

```
Solve[pol == p + q + r - b && a + b == p + q + r, pol, {b, q, p, r}]
```

I am confused about "pol" and its position ``Solve[pol == p + q + r - b && a + b == p + q + r, ? , {b, q, p, r}]". I can not find any similar examples like this in the help document. How does it work? Is "pol" an expression or a variable? May I have more examples?

It is also posted at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3008281?p_p_auth=Lpw74FtJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With two equations you can generally solve for one variable while eliminating one variable. However, you get the same result solving for `pol` irrespective of the variable chosen for elimination (`b | q | p | r`).

```
Solve[pol == p + q + r - b && a + b == p + q + r, pol, {#}][[1]] & /@ 
  {b, q, p, r}

(* {{pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}} *)
```

Further, in this case, `Solve` doesn't care if you ask to eliminate one or more variables.

```
Solve[pol == p + q + r - b && a + b == p + q + r, pol, #][[1]] & /@ 
 Subsets[{b, q, p, r}, {1, 4}]

(* {{pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, 
    {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, 
    {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}, {pol -> a}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Another query is about the usage of "[[1]]". I think it means "Flatten". However, I can not find any similar examples(without the head but only two square brackets) in the help document of MMA 13.3. May I have more examples about this?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Part`